# Firebox XTM21 failing to route

Tags: firewall, router, watchguard, firebox

So I have bought a new XTM 21 appliance from Watchguard. This god awe-full thing will not route any traffic no matter what rules I apply in the firewall setup. When the syslog doesn't crash as I'm viewing it I can see all the traffic being blocked by a policy called "internal policy" that does not exist anywhere I can find.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Thanks, D

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/259399/watchguard-firebox-xtm21-refusing-to-route

Comment: Yea wasn't quite sure witch site to post this to so I did both.

Comment: Please don't do that. The moderators will decide which is the best location if it's in the wrong place.

Comment: Didn't realize they moved post to different sites. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed an XTM23 and din't experience any problems like you're describing.

That being said, if you just bought the unit than you've got 1 year of their LiveSecurity service, which includes technical support. My suggestion would be to give Watchguard a call.

Comment: So, turns out I'm my own worst enemy. I had no intention of using any of the additional services that came with the firebox so i didn't register it. BAD IDEA. These things are black holes of traffic until you register them with Watchguard. Sigh....